# Specific issue using pack while creating a layout

Tags: python, button, tkinter, frame, pack

I must use tkinter library to create GUI.

I have this code:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):

    resx=1600
    resy=900

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
        self.createWidgets()
        master.minsize(self.resx, self.resy)
        master.maxsize(self.resx, self.resy)

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.hi_there = tk.Button(self)
        self.hi_there["text"] = "Create new window"
        self.hi_there["command"] = self.PlayMode
        self.hi_there.pack(side="top")

    def ShowMenu(self, master):
        print("Here I need DELETE master, in my case PlayM")

    def PlayMode(self):
        PlayM = tk.Tk()
        PlayM.minsize(self.resx, self.resy)
        PlayM.maxsize(self.resx, self.resy)
        PlayM.title("Game")

        bf= tk.Frame(PlayM, bg="blue")
        bf.pack(side="bottom", fill=tk.X, expand = 1)
        lbTEST=tk.Label(bf)
        lbTEST["text"] = "TESTING"
        lbTEST.pack()

        mf = tk.Frame(PlayM,bg="red")
        mf.pack(side="right", fill=tk.Y, expand=1)
        self.LogOut = tk.Button(mf)
        self.LogOut["text"] = "LOGOUT"
        self.LogOut.pack()
        self.LogOut["command"] = self.ShowMenu(PlayM)

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.master.title("Useless think")
app.mainloop()
```

I need something like this picture:

[image]

I don't know why my code is not working. When I pack my `bf` (bottom frame) and set `side = "bottom"`, but it appears in the middle of the screen. Why?
Same with `side = "right"` when I pack `mf` (menu frame)

And I have one more question. About logout button. I set command's method `"ShowMenu"`.

When I run my code, this method is started automatically only once, but when I click to button nothing happens. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have a critical flaw in your code. You should not be creating more than one instance of `Tk`. If you need to create additional windows, create instances of `Toplevel`.

> When I pack my bf (bottom frame) and set side = "bottom", but it appears in the middle of the screen. Why?

You set `expand` to `1` for both `mf` and `mf` so each will end up taking half of the available space in the window. If you simply set `expand` to 0 (zero) or `False` for `bf`, it will only take up as much space as necessary.

```
bf.pack(side="bottom", fill=tk.X, expand = 0)
```

As a general rule, you should only set a true value for `expand` on a single widget (the "hero" widget), unless you want to distribute extra space equally among widgets.

> When I run my code, this method is started automatically only once, but when I click to button nothing happens. Why?

Because you're telling it to run. Take a look at this code:

```
self.LogOut["command"] = self.ShowMenu(PlayM)
```

It is exactly the same as this code:

```
result = self.ShowMenu(PlayM)
self.logOut["command"] = result
```

See the problem?

The `command` attribute requires a *reference* to a function. Roughly translated, that means you can't use `()`. If you need to pass in an argument to the command, the typical solution is to use `functools.partial` or `lambda` to create a reference to an anonymous function that will call the real function with the argument:

```
self.logOut["command"] = lambda arg=PlayM: self.ShowMenu(arg)
```

Comment: as always, Bryan answers this way better than me ;-)

Comment: Special thanks to Bryan and all others ;) All answers for my question was really useful. 
I want ask to one more question.  Does anybody use tkinter library in "real life"? Or it is just "university" language?(just for students playing). I am asking because i have problems to find solid documentation sometimes.

Comment: @DoctorCZE I would say that, from my perspective, tkinter is useful to learn about creating GUI (in general) and to rapidly prototyping simple UIs, maybe for personal projects. I don't think tkinter is nowadays used by companies since there are modern ("better") alternatives, for example Kivy, and because nowadays UIs tend to be pushed to the browser.

Comment: @DoctorCZE I can share that is is great for rapidly prototyping things. But in contrary to nbros opinion, it is still used for commercial applications. Not broadly used but still used. For solid documentation, use the TCL Docs.

Comment: @DoctorCZE: I've used it in real life to create GUIs used in a professional setting.

Comment: Ty to all for reply.  Now I am little bit less depressed from tkinter :D.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any specific reason why you use pack method instead of grid?

You could configure your Application frame like:

```
self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)    #make the first "upper" row expand
self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=0)    #leave the second "lower" row and do not expand it

self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=0) # first column, do not expand
self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1) # second columnd, DO expand
self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=0) # third column, do not expand
```

on your mainframe/application class and then call:

```
bf.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=tk.NW+tk.SE) # span over three columns
lf.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NW+tk.SE) # default is to span over one column
rf.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=tk.NW+tk.SE)
```

**Edit**

I am very sorry, i forgot to mention about the logout button.
You call the event handler at binding time, therefore it will be executed there.

If you want to have it pass values either use:

- command=lambda parent=PlayM: self.ShowMenu(parent)
- use a class object to store youre parent reference to at creation time `self._Parent = PlayM` and use this inside ShowMenu

I personally prefer storing objects for single values. if you have many windows to destroy, I would use the lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the problems already mentioned by *Bryan Oakley* and the solution given by *R4PH43L* using `grid`, here's a possible solution for your layout only using `pack`.

The idea is that by using `side="left"` (or `side="right"`) and then `side="top"` (or `side="bottom"`) does not work the way you may be expecting. 
Within a frame you should just be using values for `side` (when packing the widgets in that same frame) which are either vertical (`"top"` or `"bottom"`) or horizontal (`"right"` or `"left"`), but not *both*. Thus to accomplish layouts like yours using only `pack` you need additional frames!

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):

    resx=400
    resy=200

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, bg="red")
        self.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
        self.create_widgets()
        master.geometry("400x200+100+500")

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.hi_there = tk.Button(self)
        self.hi_there["text"] = "Create new window"
        self.hi_there["command"] = self.play_mode
        self.hi_there.pack(side="top")

    def show_menu(self, master):
        print("Here I need DELETE master, in my case play_m")

    def play_mode(self):
        # Using a Toplevel instead of a Tk
        # You should have just one Tk in your app
        play_m = tk.Toplevel()
        play_m.geometry("400x200+100+500")
        play_m.title("Game")

        top_frame = tk.Frame(play_m, bg="blue")       
        top_frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        left_top_frame = tk.Frame(top_frame, bg="white")
        left_top_frame_label = tk.Label(left_top_frame, text="left top frame")
        left_top_frame_label.pack()
        left_top_frame.pack(side="left", fill="y")

        middle_top_frame = tk.Frame(top_frame, bg="black")

        middle_top_frame_button = tk.Button(middle_top_frame, text="Logout", command=play_m.destroy)
        middle_top_frame_button.pack()
        middle_top_frame.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

        right_top_frame = tk.Frame(top_frame, bg="white")
        right_top_frame_label = tk.Label(right_top_frame, text="right top frame")
        right_top_frame_label.pack()
        right_top_frame.pack(side="right", fill="y")

        bottom_frame = tk.Frame(play_m, bg="yellow")
        bottom_frame_label = tk.Label(bottom_frame, text="bottom frame")
        bottom_frame_label.pack()        
        bottom_frame.pack(side="top", fill="both")


root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.master.title("Useless think")
app.mainloop()
```

Here's the result of the main `Tk` window on a OS X  (Sierra):

[image]

Second toplevel

[image]

I changed a little bit the sizes for the sake of exposition. I also renamed the methods to use `_` and lower case letters.